# c part of print is not working on linux

Tags: c, linux

The program should printf two birds flying in two elypses. When birds are in the same place, the program should change their colour. Function `koloruj` should do it, but it dosn't work. Only last colour from switch is printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
char tab[30][80];
void czysc()
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 80; j++)
        {
            tab[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
typedef struct
{
    char nazwa[10];
    int wspolrzedna_x;
    int wspolrzedna_y;
} obiekt;

void koloruj (int c)
{
    int i,j;
    switch(c)
    {
    case 0:
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 80; j++)
            {
                printf("\x1b[31m %c \n", tab[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 80; j++)
            {
                printf("\x1b[32m %c \n", tab[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 80; j++)
            {
                printf("\x1b[33m %c \n", tab[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 80; j++)
            {
                printf("\x1b[34m %c \n", tab[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 80; j++)
            {
                printf("\x1b[35m %c \n", tab[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 80; j++)
            {
                printf("\x1b[36m %c \n", tab[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        break;
    }
}
void conv1(int mod,int x1 ,int y1)
{
    char znak [3][3] =  {"-.-", "/*\\", "\\./"};
    int n = mod%4;
    switch(n)
    {
    case 0:
        tab[y1][x1] = znak[0][0];
        tab[y1][x1+1] = znak[0][1];
        tab[y1][x1+2] = znak[0][2];
        break;
    case 1:
        tab[y1][x1] = znak[2][0];
        tab[y1][x1+1] = znak[2][1];
        tab[y1][x1+2] = znak[2][2];
        break;
    case 2:
        tab[y1][x1] = znak[0][0];
        tab[y1][x1+1] = znak[0][1];
        tab[y1][x1+2] = znak[0][2];
        break;
    case 3:
        tab[y1][x1] = znak[1][0];
        tab[y1][x1+1] = znak[1][1];
        tab[y1][x1+2] = znak[1][2];
        break;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int x1, x2, y1, y2, a, b, i, j, rx = 18, ry = 8, z = 0, g = 0, c = 0;
    float t1;
    obiekt obiekt_1 = {"ptaszek", x1, y1};
    obiekt obiekt_2 = {"samolot", x2, y2};
    for (a = 0; a<5; a++)
    {
        t1 = 0;
        for (b = 0; b<64; b++)
        {
            x1 = 106 / 2 + rx*cos(t1);
            y1 = 24 / 2 + ry*sin(t1);
            conv1(z, x1, y1);
            x2 = 36/2 + rx*cos(t1+2.6);
            y2 = 24/2 + ry*sin(t1+2.6);
            conv1(g, x2, y2);
            if (x1 = x2)
            {
                if (y1 = y2)
                    c++;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 80; j++)
                {
                    printf ("%c", tab[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            koloruj(c);
            czysc();

            z++;
            g++;
            t1+ = 0.1;

            usleep (100000);
            system ("clear");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What terminal are you using with linux? What terminal was the program hard-coded for?

Comment: `math.h` defines M_PI

Comment: @richard  The C spec does not specify  `M_PI` in `math.h`.  What is your reference that indicates it does?  Perhaps a Linux one?

Comment: @chux my bad, I did not check the spec.  I only looked in the GNU library `glibc`, so not Linux (Linux is part of GNU (the project), not GNU part of Linux). Is it in one of the headers, as I remember my teacher 30 years ago telling someone off for the same thing (not using pi from the library).

Comment: gcc should give you a warning when you use an assignment inside the parentheses of an if statement.  It's good idea to look at those even when your code compiles

Comment: @richard Common sense is that Linux is the Kernel and GNU is the userland. E.g. there exists **Debian GNU/Linux**, but also **Debian GNU/Hurd**. So, none is part of the other

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your comparison:

```
    if(x1=x2)
    if(y1=y2)
```

In C you use `==` as comparison operator, you make assignments here which evaluate to the value of the assignment.

Furthermore, your print function can be shortened severly:

```
void koloruj (int c)
{
     int i,j;
     for(i=0; i<30; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<80; j++)
            {
                printf("\x1b[3%dm %c \n", c+1, tab[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: Also, the intention for that print function appears to be to fill an 80x30 terminal with data from a table, but for each pixel it writes space-pixel-space-linefeed, so it will not form a proper image.

Comment: Well, yes, probably if his terminal is what we expect it to be ;) I just tried to address the original problem and show up a way, how to shorten koloruj a bit without altering the behaviour otherwise. There's probably still a lot to fix ;)

Comment: Now program dont print anything.

Comment: @MichałSiwoszek As I said, there may be many errors. One more mistake is, that c is constantly incremented, you probably want to make sure that it remains in a sensible range (e.g. 0-5). And _that other guy_ is probably correct, too, with his comment